# C5027 "Move assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted"

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have this code:

```
template < typename TFunc >
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(TFunc func) : func_(func) {}
  Foo(Foo<TFunc> const &) = delete;
  Foo<TFunc> & operator=(Foo<TFunc> const &) = delete;
  Foo(Foo<TFunc> &&) = default;
  Foo<TFunc> & operator=(Foo<TFunc> &&) = default;
private:
  TFunc func_;
};

int main()
{
  auto func = []() {};
  auto f = Foo<decltype(func)>(func);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code with Visual Studio 2015 with the `/Wall`flag, I get the following warning:

```
C5027 'Foo<main::<lambda_e5404f82e4b38ca1d164ce09039df46c>>': move assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
```

I don't understand why the move assignment operator would be implicitly defined as deleted while it is explicitely defined as defaulted. Any idea?

Comment: It is pretty important to keep your VS2015 install updated, this bug was repaired in Update 1.

Comment: I have version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, isn't it the latest version?

Comment: I get this warning too (with`/Wall`).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo How on earth is this a bug?

Comment: @T.C.: It's a pretty major GCC and Clang bug, if Vittorio is right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They simply don't have a warning for this.

Comment: I meant that I couldn't reproduce the unexpected warning on any other major compiler - removed my misleading comment. I now see that it could actually be useful.

Comment: @T.C.: Okay, well, still, I'd probably deem it buggy! (in the sense of "does not perform as expected" not the sense of "does not abide by standards")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of a lambda expression is not copy/move assignable: it has a deleted copy assignment operator and no move assignment operator.

If a class has a non-static data member that is not move assignable, then a defaulted move assignment operator of that class will be defined as deleted.

The compiler warning is simply advising you of this fact. Whether that warning is useful is a different question.

Comment: then is it a bug that it can actually compile with an extra `auto g = std::move(f)`?

Comment: @user1735003 No, that's not assignment.